# Sql cursor locking

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor, locking

I would like to help me with a question for which I couldn't understand the documentation from msdn.
If I have the following sql code:

```
declare C1 cursor for select * from tableA
open C1
fetch next from C1 into @a, @b..
while @@fetch_status = 0
 .. do something very time consuming for each row
 fetch next from C1 into @a, @b..
end
close c1
```

When is tableA locked for updating? during cursor declare? during Open, during fetch? or from open to close?

Thank you

Comment: you are right marc_s, I have updated it

Comment: The row(s) that you're updating will be locked *while* the `UPDATE` statement runs - or if you have them inside a transaction, then they will be locked until the transaction commits (or is rolled back)

Comment: so the records are locked at row level, not on table level? PS:I am not making changes to A table, based on @a I make changes in other tables in database

Comment: Yes, by default, SQL Server uses **row-level locking** only. If you make more than 5000 updates in a single transaction, SQL Server might do a **lock escalation** and lock the entire table in question to avoid having to handle too many individual locks

Comment: Ok, can you copy it to an answer so I can close this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row(s) that you're updating will be locked exclusively **while** the `UPDATE` statement runs. Or if you all the statements inside a single transaction, then these rows will be exclusively locked until the transaction commits (or is rolled back)

By default, SQL Server uses **row-level locking**. But if you make more than 5000 updates in a single transaction, SQL Server might do a **lock escalation** and lock the entire table in question to avoid having to handle too many individual locks.

Comment: I'm a little confused as there is no `UPDATE` statement in the code in the question. Is there an implicit `UPDATE` somehow?

Comment: @JohnHenderson: well, the OP did say: *When is tableA locked for updating?* so I assumed the part he's not showing would contain one or more `UPDATE` statement(s)..

Comment: I see. I took that "When is tableA locked for updating?" to mean "When is tableA locked for updating by another command?". I see how the other reading ("When is tableA locked for updating by the statements within the cursor while loop?") is possible but I don't think that is the case as in one of the comments on the question, the poster said "PS:I am not making changes to A table, based on @a I make changes in other tables in database".